# How to check disk space when running python script?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a script that is going to download a lot of data from the internet. But, I have no idea how long will it take or how big the data it will be.

To be more precise I want to analyze some live videos and for that I will download the content using *youtube-dl*. Since I want to leave it running for a week or two, is there a way so that can avoid running into low memory problem, that the computer checks on a specific interval what is my memory status and if it is below a certain value to stop the execution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shutil.disk_usage(path)` from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?highlight=free%20space):

> shutil.disk_usage(path)
>
> Return disk usage statistics about the given path as a named tuple with the attributes total, used and free, which are the amount of
>   total, used and free space, in bytes. On Windows, path must be a
>   directory; on Unix, it can be a file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use [shutil.disk_usage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.disk_usage).

```py
total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("/")
```